# AS3 MOUSE_OUT called for a movie clip I just removed

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseout

In my current project I'm using few copies of a movie clip that has some buttons on it. One of the buttons is responsible for removing the targeted copy.
It's working well but as the copy disappears it calls the MOUSE_OUT event on itself, and I'm getting Error #1009 as a result.
Found one workaround (I'm killing the copy as a part of MOUSE_OUT event) but it's still not letting me sleep - what is the proper way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... have you tried `clip.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, yourmouseoutevent);`...

Comment: I'm sure you're not stupid, but you need to learn the programming language! :{D (WATCH YOUR LANGUAGE!)